# how can I add a list item into a list in Netlogo?

Tags: list, addition, netlogo

I have a list called first-list [].
anytime I produce other lists such as [2 3],[1 4 6],... I want to add these list into that first-list:
first-list :[[2 3],[1 4 6], ...].
how can I do that in NetLogo?
I know by lput I can add items but not lists into a list

Answer (score 2):

of-course you can, for example:

```
let mylist [1 2]
set mylist lput [3 4] mylist
print mylist ; prints [1 2 [3 4]]
```

If you have variables, such as:

```
let x 42
let y "string"
```

to create a list with them, you need to use the built-in primitive "list", as such:

```
let mylist2 list x y
```

To create a list with variables that has more than 2 variables (or just 1), you need to encapsulate it with parentheses, such as:

```
let mylist3 (list x y x)
```

I strongly suggest you refer to the netlogo dictionary, in the link https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list

You can only create a list using the "[" and "]" if you are using primitive numbers and strings, such as [1 2 "three"], but if you want to create a list with variables you need to use the "list" primitive, such as (list x y "a string" 5)

Comment: Thank you dear Demius